# Detect Share Contract in UWP

Tags: uwp, share, contract

I know it is not possible to share files with other apps in xbox one, but I don't know how to check it? I guess it is using ApiInformation, but how?

Notice I know how to check the device family, but I'd like to check the feature instead, so when the share feature is implemented in xbox I don't need to change the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is currently no way to detect whether the underlying platform supports the Share contract. All that happens is that the ShowShareUI method returns without doing anything if the platform does not support Share.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now since Windows 10 Anniversary Update (aka RS1). If you change the **Target Version** in **Properties** to `Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)`.
[image]
You can then use [DataTransferManager.IsSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataTransferManager_IsSupported) method to determine if the device supports sharing. This method returns true if the device supports sharing, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need the solution, `DataTransferManager` now has a method called `IsSupported`.

Check this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386405/detect-if-share-ui-is-supported-in-current-device-uwp/42548152#42548152) to my question.